# Grab the text inputted in the console after running a program in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm not sure exactly if the title made it clear, but I want to save the text typed in the same line while executing a program in C.

For example, if I type:
    ./myprogram samplestring

I want to save samplestring as a variable in the C program.  Not sure if this is possible or not, and sorry if I'm not being clear, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Are you looking for `argv[1]`?

Comment: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html will help. A better title for your question would be "how to get the command line arguments supplied to my C program".

Comment: I think his main issue was that he didn't know that this were 'command line arguments' ! Hence the difficulty to search for it, to find duplicates and to have a clear title.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for argv[1], and @mah, thanks for the article.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int count;

  printf ("This program was called with \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);

  if (argc > 1)
  {
      for (count = 1; count < argc; count++)
      {
          printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", count, argv[count]);
      }
  }
  else
  {
      printf("The command had no other arguments.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```